# How can I kill tmux windows from the window list?

Tags: tmux

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, <kbd>W</kbd>, tmux shows the list of all current windows and their panes. How can I kill a window and its panes from within this list view?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is a new capability of the `choose-tree` feature in tmux 2.8.  From [tmux(1)](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1#choose-tree):

> ```
> Key   Function
> Enter Choose selected item
> Up    Select previous item
> Down  Select next item
> x     Kill selected item
> ```

So after you've navigated to the right window, press `<tmux prefix> + x`, then when you are prompted:

`Kill window 1?`

...press `y` to accept.  This also works for killing individual panes, or even whole sessions.

Comment: is there a way to close without using the prompt?

Comment: @kendfss
There's no way to bypass the prompt, according to the [current source](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/57fec74966e39d8594fec9766609309879cb4f03/window-tree.c#L1282).
But you could invoke `choose-tree` with a `kill` command in the template, ie. `:choose-tree "kill-window -t %1"`, so it will immediately kill the one you choose (with Enter).